# Clarification regarding the monotone convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory, integration

I have a simple question about the monontone convergence theorem.  Let $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty]$ be a sequence of nonnegative, extended real valued, measureable functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose the sequence is monotone increasing i.e. $0 \leq f_1 \leq f_2 \leq \ldots$, with the inequalities holding pointwise. Define $f$ to be the pointwise limit. The monotone convergence theorem asserts that $f$ is also measureable and $\int f  = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n $.

I'm wondering... when we say that $f$ is the pointwise limit of the $f_n$, does that include the possibility that at some point $x$ the sequence diverges to infinity? Say $f_n(x) = n$ for all $n$, for example. Then would we say $f_n(x) \to \infty$? I ask because the way you define convergence to infinity is a little different i.e. $x_n \to \infty$ when, for all $M < \infty$ there's and $N > 0$ so $n \geq N$ implies $x_n > M$. It seems a bit suspect that both kinds of convergence are implicitly being allowed in the statement. But, I suspect this is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In most of measure theory one allows functions to take values on the "extended real line", i.e. $[-\infty,\infty]$.

The infinities in the Monotone Convergence Theorem play no role, in the sense that if they appear on a null-set then you can forget about them. An if they appear in a set of positive measure, then both sides of the equality become infinity.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome!